# $\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+} \frac{1}{h^2}\big [\frac{f(v+hu)+ f(v-hu)}{2} - f(v)\big]$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm asked to find:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+} \frac{1}{h^2} \bigg[\frac{f(v+hu)+ f(v-hu)}{2} - f(v)\bigg]$$
where
$f(x,y,z) = (x+y^2)e^z$

and
$v=\left<1,0,0 \right>, u=\left<3,2,1 \right>$.

The equation reminds me of the directional derivative, as well as divided centered differences, but I'm stuck as to how to compute this problem. I would like some hints or references about general methods to solving these vector derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limit can be estimated by direct substitution of $v$ and $u$  and one algebraic simplifications:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(\frac{f(v+hu)+f(v-hu)}{2}-f(v)\Big)&=
\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(\frac{(3h+1+4h^2)e^h+(-3h+1+4h^2)e^{-h}}{2}-1\Big)
\end{align}
$$
and so on.

---

Another way to do it, which can be applied to other situations is through the use of some multivariate Calculus. The function $f$ in the OP is  twice  continuously differentiable ($f\in\mathcal{C}^2$). Using Taylor's expansion we have that

$$f(v+w)=f(v) + f'(v)w + \frac{1}{2} f''(v)(w, w) + r(w)$$
where $\frac{|r(w)|}{\|w\|^3}\xrightarrow{w\rightarrow0}0$.

Then, the expression in brackets becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(v+hu)+ f(v-hu)}{2} - f(v)&=\frac{f(v+hu)-f(v)}{2} + \frac{f(v-hu)-f(v)}{2}\\
&=h\frac{f'(v)u-f'(v)u}{2} + \frac12 h^2f''(v)(u,u) + r(hu)
\end{align}
$$
where $\frac{|r(hu)|}{|h^3|}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0$.
From this, one gets that the limit in the OP is

$$\frac{1}{2} f''(v)(u,u).$$

$f''(x,y,z)$ (the Hessian of $f$ ) is given by

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{xx}f & \partial_{xy}f & \partial_{xz}f\\
\partial{yx}f & \partial_{yy}f & \partial_{yz}f \\
\partial_{zx}f & \partial_{zy}f & \partial_{zz}f
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &  e^z\\
0 & 2e^z & 2ye^z\\
e^z & 2ye^z & (x+y^2)e^z
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

So, at $v=[1,0,0]^\intercal$,

$$ f''(v)= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &  1\\
0 & 2 &0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The limit is then

$$\frac12 \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 &1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &  1\\
0 & 2 &0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$